# How to Connect & test polycom IP Phone with FreeSwitch V1.9

Tags: testing, freeswitch

Required components

1. Freeswitch V1.9
2. Intranet with at-least 3 available IP Ports (one each for Freeswitch,Polycom IP Phone, and free Linphone)
3. Polycom IP Phone VVX411 Model (tested currently with, you can try with other 
   IP Phones)
4. Android/iOS/Windows mobile Phone with free Lin SIP Phone installed and configured with Freeswitch

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question about software or programming, so off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xml version="1.0">
<include>
              <user id="1001">
                <params>
                    <!--default password 1111 -->
                    <param name="password" value="$${default_password}"/>
                    <param name="vm-password" value="1001"/>
                </params>
                <variables>
                      <variable name="toll_allow" value="domestic,international,local"/>
                      <variable name="accountcode" value="1001"/>
                      <variable name="user_context" value="default"/>
                      <variable name="effective_caller_id_name" value="Polycom 1001"/>
                      <variable name="effective_caller_id_number" value="1001"/>
                      <variable name="outbound_caller_id_name" value="$${outbound_caller_name}"/>
                      <variable name="outbound_caller_id_number" value="$${outbound_caller_id}"/>
                      <variable name="callgroup" value="Techsupport"/>
                </variables>
            </user>
        </include>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<HTML>
<p>
<ul>
  <li>1. Run Freeswitch V1.9 server  (How to install/run Freeswitch https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Installation)</li>
  <li>2. Network Settings (For these testing 802.1x Authentication is disabled on Phone)</li>
   <ul>
 <li>a. configure static IP or DHCP enabled for IP Phone</li>
 <li>To check the current phone configuration
  Press Home Button -> Settings -> Status ->  Platform -> Phone</li>
 </ul>

  
 <li>3. Connect your phone to the IP Network through the LAN Cable (if router is not PoE, use the Power adapter)</li>
  
 <li>4. Create an XML file for Polycom phone extension into Free switch configuration
 (Default extension details for Free switch installation =C:\FreeSwitch\Win32\Release\conf\directory\default (i.e. my current install directory)
 I have configured and tested with the 1001.xml and below are file contents. I will leave the tester to explore extension configuration from Free switch confluence
    </li>
    enter code here
 <li>5. Phone Configuration:  Configure Polycom IP Phone for Freeswitch Server
  Phone Configuration:  Configure Polycom IP Phone for Freeswitch Server</li>
 
 <ul>
 <li><b>Step 1</b> </li>
 <li>Go to Settings ->  Advanced (456 is default password on Polycom Phone VVX411) -> Administration Settings -> Call Server Configuration -> SIP </li>
 <li>Set below values
  <br>Server Address = Freeswitch server IP Address (192.168.1.100 in my case)
  <br>Port = 5060
  <br>Register=Yes 
  <br>Transport=Tcp Only
 </li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
 <li><b>Step 2 </b></li>
 <li>Go to Settings ->  Advanced (456 is default password on Polycom Phone VVX411) -> Administration Settings -> Line Configuration -> Line 1</li>
 <li>Set Values -> Address : 1001</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
  <li><b>Step 3</b></li>
  <li>Go to Settings ->  Advanced (456 is default password on Polycom Phone VVX411) -> Administration Settings -> Line Configuration -> Line 1 -> Authentication</li>
  <li>Domain: 192.168.0.100</li>
  <li>UserID : 1001</li>
  <li>Password: 1001 (** check your default password)</li>
  </ul>
</ul>

</HTML>
```